# No Load kml in Openlayers MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openlayers

I have a problem to load a kml map using OpenLayers.

I used this in this example:

http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/sundials.html

I put the following script to load the kml

```
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('OpenLayers WMS','http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0', { layers: 'basic' }, {});
var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google", { type: G_PHYSICAL_MAP });
var geomor = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
                projection: map.displayProjection,
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "/Shapes/Geomorfologia/est_temp2.kml",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                        extractStyles: true,
                        extractAttributes: true                        
                    })
                })
            });

map.addLayers([wms, gphy, geomor]);
```

Only this KML is not loading from the folder where the KML is within the Visual Studio folder.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong.

Comment: When you debug this in localhost, does that folder exist relative to the page? This isn't really an OpenLayers problem, I don't think.

Comment: Yes this folder exists in relation to the page, but does not open. 
I downloaded stuff OpenLayers, which contains examples with kml, and also do not work. Would any other solution to my problem, I need urgent finish this project and lack just that. @John Barça

Comment: Well, the OpenLayers example above works. Which one did you download that did not work?

Comment: You will need to produce a working html/javascript page in jsFiddle or similar so that we can attempt to debug the problem. Having no access to your ASP.NET page there isn't much anyone can do from what you have said so far.

Comment: All projects containing kml, will not work on the local machine. In jsFiddle, how can I link a kml file? @John Barça

Comment: Put it on github or similar? Are you sure your KML is valid? Does it open in Google Earth OK?